# height:auto; doesn't work even when parent elements are 100%

Tags: css

I have an image that is larger than the screen in both height and width. html and body are set to 100%. Yet when I do `width:90%;height:auto;` width gets set but height hangs over.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5tpUf/) (which actually works fine).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                height:100%;
                width:100%;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            img {
                height:auto;
                width:95%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="foo.png" /> /*img is 1288 wide by 1072 tall */
    </body>
</html>
```

**update**
setting max has no effect (at least when you copy and paste this exact text).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                    height:100%;
                    width:100%;
                    overflow:hidden;
                }
                img {
                    height:auto;
                    width:95%;
                    max-height:95%;
                    max-width:95%;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/743349main2_Timelapse_Sun_2k-16x9-673.jpg" /> /*img is 1288 wide by 1072 tall */
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A fiddle that serves to demonstrate the expected behavior isn't going to be very helpful in debugging your issue, unfortunately. See if you can produce a test case that demonstrates your issue instead.

Comment: its not letting me update

Comment: this is my post. its vague and unclear and already way off the rails. its not going to help anybody.

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand anything from your image

Check fiddle in here http://jsfiddle.net/nowak2009/4p9j2/

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img {
    height:auto;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:10%;    
    width:100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here comes your solution

```
min-height: inherit;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

set it for image

Adjust accordingly?

Here is full HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
body{width: 100%;}
img {
height: auto;
max-width: 95%;
width: 100%;
}
</style>    
</head>
<body id="page1">
<img src="http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/images/743349main2_Timelapse_Sun_2k-16x9-673.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this works perfectly in jsfiddle but, not in chrom or ie. ive tried using doctypes and meta viewport.

Comment: yeah but 60%. i need it to be the max width or height possible and then adjust the other one accordingly

Comment: I guess the best you can do is describe - what you want to do? **result**

Comment: If you need it 100% width - use 100%, not 95%